# Showing all tables with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to retrieve all table data from DB by using SQLAlchemy. I wrote my code, seems ok to me but I cannot retrieve required columns: bookname, author, publisher, etc columns. Probably I made a mistake on my code but couldn't find it. Kindly asking for your help.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from addBook import Books

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://///Users/myUser//flaskProject/flasktestdb.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route("/bookshelves")
def bookshelves():
    books = Books.query.all()
     return render_template("bookshelves.html", books=books)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

addBook.py (Book class)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://///Users/myUser//flaskProject/flasktestdb.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Books(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    bookname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    author = db.Column(db.String(80))
    publisher = db.Column(db.String(80))
    category = db.Column(db.String())
    pagenumber = db.Column(db.Integer())
    status = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self, bookname, author, publisher, category, pagenumber, status):
        self.bookname = bookname
        self.author = author
        self.publisher = publisher
        self.category = category
        self.pagenumber = pagenumber
        self.status = status
```

bookshelves.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Book Shelves{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h3>Book Shelves</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="card-columns">
        {% for book in books %}
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{ book.bookname }}</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{ book.author }}</h6>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Publisher: {{ book.publisher }}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Category: {{ books.category }}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Page Number: {{ book.pagenumber }}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Status: {{ book.status }}</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Edit Book</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Delete Book</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Can't retrieve specific columns, or can't retrieve any data at all? The placement of that `db.create_all()` is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Can't retrieve any data at all. Placement of the `db.create_all()` has corrected changed but result is the same. Any other help?

Comment: Is there a .db file? If so, open it with the sqlite3 command and see if you can query data by hand.

Comment: Sure, there is .db file and I can retrieve all data by querying from sqlite3 tool. Can you see a problem on my code?

Comment: The only other thing that jumps out is `sqlite://///Users/...`, which may need to be `sqlite:///Users/...` (that is, remove two slashes).

Comment: It's not about slashes. The code suddenly decided to work even I haven't changed anything. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The import model needs to be stated after the db instantiation. Try this

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://///Users/myUser//flaskProject/flasktestdb.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from addBook import Books
```

Comment: Trust me adding or removing 'body' tag at the end of 'endblock' doesn't change anything.

Comment: In that case, I have learned something new...

Comment: I wasn't sure if you got my new answer, I edited my old one. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Nope, I haven't got your new answer.